# how do i pass large parameters from one jsp to another?

Tags: java, html, jsp

i have some huge parameters and i want to pass them to another page **without using thr URL** currently i am passing with the `url` . i tried with **session** also but parameters are huge so it gave `null`

code :

`out.println("<a href='itemdetails.jsp?pid="+p.getPid()+"&features="+p.getFeatures()+"&price="+p.getPrice()+"&pname="+p.getPname()+"&img="+p.getImg()+"'>");`

i basically want the url to pass one variable in `URL` so that i could use it in `requestDispatcher` from java page

Comment: *i tried with session also but parameters are huge so it gave null*. What do you mean by this? If you insist on passing these parameters in the url, use a `HashMap`?

Comment: no i don't want to pass parameters with URL

Comment: *i basically want the url to pass one variable in URL* Why do you say this then?

Comment: i may not be clear ... i want the URL to be like this : `http://localhost:8083/devilmaycry/Register/itemdetails.jsp?pid=8881` instead of `http://localhost:8083/devilmaycry/Register/itemdetails.jsp?pid=8881&features=Snapdragon%20Quad%20Core%20Processor-4.7%20inch%20IPS+%20Display-Android%20v4.2%20OS-8%20MP%20Primary%20Camera&price=22,000&pname=Nexus%204&img=http://www.lg.com/us/images/cell-phones/lge960/gallery/medium01-2.jpg`

Comment: Unless these huge parameters are being supplied by the user, you shouldn't be passing them to the page in the first place. Put them in the session, maybe pass a key to them to the jsp. It's difficult to tell what is appropriate because you supply _very little_ information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This may be ridiculous, but if you desperately want to shorten the url, them you can make the link in a form and post it back

```
<form action="itemdetails.jsp?pid=<%=p.getPid()%>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="features" value="<%=p.getFeatures()%>" />
    ....
    <button type="submit">...</button>
</form>
```

(you should think about using `jstl` instead of `scriptlet`)

Comment: that's the biggest ,issue i am unable to use `variables` in action attribute ..it is giving DOUBLE_WHITESPACE in query error

Comment: @amolsingh if you have large data needs to be sent then **POST** is the only way

Comment: @amolsingh if you want to remove the space in the url (because your data, e.g name, contains space), then your approach (shorten the url like the question) is totally wrong. You need to encode your url instead